# mongdump "positional arguments not allowed"

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

What does mongodump not accept these arguments:

```
mongodump xyzserver.mlab.com:42129 /u mydb-test-restore-mongouser /p xyz /c shapeLink /d mydb-test-mongolab
```

Error:

> positional arguments not allowed: [xyzserver.com:42129 ]
>
> try 'mongodump --help' for more information

I am using v3.2.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to specify the host parameter with `/h` like so

```
mongodump /h xyzserver.mlab.com:42129 /u mydb-test-restore-mongouser /p xyz /c shapeLink /d mydb-test-mongolab
```

Answer (score 0):

Positional argument:

**--x** this is a positional argument: error says that this is not supported when program expecting its output argument in it's main like `main(int argc, char *argv[])`

you should use this `/x` instead in target shell environment. Because it has handling input argument just as `'/' instead '--'`